# .htaccess: apply https only if accessed via port 80

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess rule like it:

```
# Redirect to HTTPs.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Basically it'll check if I'm using HTTP instead of HTTPS. If I do, then it'll redirect to HTTPS version. It works perfectly. But I have a small problem.

When I'm running in development mode (*localhost*), I use port 8000, for instance, then I need remove this rule because it generate an error (like *ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR*). I need only open this page using HTTP, normally, I don't need HTTPS for this case.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this case before finish this post. Basically I changed to this rule:

```
# Redirect to HTTPs.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It'll check if I'm accessing via port 80, then it'll redirect to HTTPS version.